# How can we connect to database using AngularJS?

Tags: sql, database, angularjs

Iam trying to fetch data from the SQL database using AngularJS alone. Can we do it give me an idea??

Comment: No, you can't do that. AngularJs is a fronend thing. You need a layer between database and frontend like .net or node or something.

Comment: what are all the intermediate layer can be used?

Comment: Dude.. hire someone to code for you. There are some many article already available on net. Try any good one. If you struck then post your problem. Do not ask for whole solution.

Answer (score 2):

Create web services using java / .net to fetch the required data for you and call those web services from your javascript  ajax calls!!

Or if not big DB with a max size of 5 MB you can use Local DB - SQL Express. It comes in with HTML 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a sandboxed mock database --
check out http://kripken.github.io/sql.js/GUI/